# Omxplayer green flicker when orientation set to 90 or 270

Tags: pi-4, omxplayer

I have a video in 1080x1920 resolution that I want to display vertically in my 1920x1080 monitor.

```
sudo omxplayer video1.mp4
```

Outputs the video in full screen normally (stretched but that was expected since the big difference in aspect ratio, [thats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4xUY.jpg) a photo of it)

So, in order to rotate it and match its original aspect ratio with the monitor's, I used --orientation 90 and thus:

```
sudo omxplayer video1.mp4 --orientation 90
```

But when I run it this way the screen starts flickering badly with a green color ([here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1toRU.jpg) a photo of it)

Same result when instead of 90, the orientation is set to 270. Though, setting it to 180 doesn't seem to cause any flickering.

I am using a Raspberry pi 4, 4GB version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo rpi-update` fixed the issue. There seemed to be a problem after VC version 8f792e011c8a0ea3c5d47e7cc10172cc10b93c09 that got fixed.